# Set an NSMutableDictionary variable to an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

Is it possible to assign an `NSDictionary` to an `NSMutableDictionary`? For example,

```
NSMutableDictionary * root = AppDelegate.data;
```

where `AppDelegate.data` is an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want something like this, hopefully it explains itself

```
root = [AppDelegate.data mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Pedant's comment: it's mutableCopy, not MutableCopy. Standard naming conventions apply (though it was probably a typo anyway).

Comment: good catch sir, it was indeed a typo, haven't had my coffee yet this morning

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableDictionary *root = [NSMutableDictionary  dictionary];
[root addEntriesFromDictionary:AppDelegate.data];
```

This'll add all the entries from the immutable `NSDictionary` to a new mutable `NSMutableDictionary`

For future reference the Apple API's (this is the [NSMutableDictionary entry](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) contain a lot of useful information on things like this.