# How can I convert an NSDictionary to an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an existing NSDictionary that has:

```
{
    "charts_count" = 2;
    "created_at" = "2010-04-12T16:37:32Z";
    exchange = NASDAQ;
    "followers_count" = 259;
    id = 8404;
    industry = "<null>";
    "messages_count" = 1436;
    ric = "GRPN.O";
    sector = "<null>";
    symbol = GRPN;
    title = Groupon;
    "updated_at" = "2011-09-05T04:17:56Z";
}
```

How can I take these contents and put it into a new NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set an NSMutableDictionary variable to an NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116031/set-an-nsmutabledictionary-variable-to-an-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use `-mutableCopy`.

```
NSDictionary *d;
NSMutableDictionary *m = [d mutableCopy];
```

Note that `-mutableCopy` returns `id` (`Any` in Swift) so you will want to assign / cast to the right type.  It creates a shallow copy of the original dictionary.

Comment: It should be noted that this will not inherently make the dictionary objects also mutable so if you have a dictionary of arrays of more dictionaries the children will not become mutable.

Comment: @Vlad - I want to achieve exactly What you said, Need to Make inherently make the dictionary objects also mutable i.e. all children objects of the dictionary should become mutable.

Comment: @Vlad - I wanted to achieve what you said, have a dictionary that has an array and other dictionaries, need to make all children mutable inherently.

Answer (score 8):

In case of Swift

```
var tempDic: NSMutableDictionary = yourDictionary.mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in swift 3

```
let mutableDic: NSMutableDictionary =  (yourDictionary as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *newInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[newInfo setDictionary:info];
```

Also works, since you are setting the dictionary not appending. You can also use:

```
[newInfo addEntriesFromDictionary:info];
```

for the same effect and to append to existing content.